# How do I write this async IO C# code in F#?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, f#, async-await

I have this code:

```
public async Task CreateFileAsync(string filePath, byte[] bytes)
    {
        using (var sourceStream = System.IO.File.Open(filePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
        {
            sourceStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);
            await sourceStream.WriteAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }
```

I want to write it on F#, I get as far as this before I can't figure out what to do:

```
module myModule
open System.IO;
let CreateFileAsync (filePath: string, bytes : byte[]) =
    use sourceStream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate)
        |> sourceStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);
```

I have searched around but there are a couple of concepts here and I can't put them all together.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `async { .. }` workflow:

```
let createFileAsync (filePath, bytes) = async {
  use sourceStream = System.IO.File.Open(filePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate)
  sourceStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End)
  do! sourceStream.AsyncWrite(bytes, 0, bytes.Length) }
```

This is fairly imperative code, so it does not look very different in F#.